# freeradius pass current virtual server port to module

Tags: freeradius

I'm trying to use rlm_python to authenticate client with my backend.

The problem is, it seems I could not use different modules for different virtual servers and it cause my authentication backed threat all authentication request as default virtual server.

**So the question is:** Is there any way to pass a variable to module to inform the current virtual server port address?

For example something like this:

```
update control {
       Auth-Type := `/usr/bin/python /etc/test.py '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' '#{virtual-server}'`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use %{Packet-Dst-Port} which will expand to the destination port in the received UDP packet.

To access it in the rlm_python module you'd need to do something like:

```
update request {
    Packet-Dst-Port := "%{Packet-Dst-Port}"
}
python
```

To convert it to a real attribute first.

Comment: thanks it works, is there any variable that indicate virtual server name? for example "default","vserver01",....

Comment: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/master/src/main/xlat.c#L1833

``%{Virtual-Server}``